# Rendering and saving SSRS report in PDF

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I need to save SSRS report in PDF programmatically (vb.net).  I know when the report is rendered, we can save it in PDF from the triangle next to Disk icon, but I do not need to press this, rather save it using vb.net code.

Please advise.
Thanks[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggest correction in code to render report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730317/suggest-correction-in-code-to-render-report)

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
If reportViewer.ServerReport.IsReadyForRendering Then
    Dim fileData As Byte() = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF")
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Path\filename.pdf", fileData)
Else
    'report parameters are not properly set, warn user to check
End If
```