# Suggest correction in code to render report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I was suggested the following code to programmatically render SSRS report in PDF format.
I tried it but it is not working.

Can any body suggest what might be required?
Thanks

```
Dim format As String = "PDF"
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\Output.pdf"
     Dim reportPath As String = "/[Report Folder]/Invoice"

    ' Prepare Render arguments
    Dim historyID As String = Nothing
    Dim deviceInfo As String = Nothing
    Dim extension As String = Nothing
    Dim encoding As String
    Dim mimeType As String = "application/pdf"
    Dim warnings() As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning = Nothing
    Dim streamIDs() As String = Nothing
    Dim results() As Byte

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, fileName, streamIDs, warnings)


    ' Open a file stream and write out the report
    Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)
    stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length)
    stream.Close()
```

Comment: You can't write directly to **C:\Output.pdf** i guess, make a directory and give write permission. Then try something like **C:\some_writable_directory\Output.pdf**

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you never assign anything to the `results` variable so the FileStream will never get anything written to it. You need to assign the result of the `Render` method to `results`:

```
results = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, fileName, streamIDs, warnings)
```